# Simple Test Servlet not working, when hosted on GoDaddy server,Why?

Tags: java, servlets

I was trying to test servlet by hosting it on shared hosting by GoDaddy server. I am compiling the code using Java SDK 5_0_22(The SDK [version](http://community.godaddy.com/groups/web-hosting/forum/topic/supported-jdk-version/) of GoDaddy server). I tested same code,folder structure, on LOCAL Tomcat5.0.27(The server [verision](http://help.godaddy.com/article/75?locale=en) of Godaddy).

But I am able to run JSP file; this proves that my account is JAVA enabled.Please help.
P.S. Every time am getting 404 error.**index.jsp is working fine.**

FolderStructure:-

WebApplication--|
                          
                |-META-INF
                          
                |-WEB-INF---|
                                               |-classes--|--test.class
                                               |-web.xml

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>test</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>test</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        </welcome-file-list>
    </web-app>
```

test.java

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */


import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 *
 * @author SAM
 */
public class test extends HttpServlet {

    /** 
     * Processes requests for both HTTP <code>GET</code> and <code>POST</code> methods.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        try {
            // TODO output your page here
            out.println("<html>");
            out.println("<head>");
            out.println("<title>Servlet test</title>");  
            out.println("</head>");
            out.println("<body>");
            out.println("<h1>Servlet test at " + request.getContextPath () + "</h1>");
            out.println("</body>");
            out.println("</html>");

        } finally { 
            out.close();
        }
    } 

    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="HttpServlet methods. Click on the + sign on the left to edit the code.">
    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>GET</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    } 

    /** 
     * Handles the HTTP <code>POST</code> method.
     * @param request servlet request
     * @param response servlet response
     * @throws ServletException if a servlet-specific error occurs
     * @throws IOException if an I/O error occurs
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        processRequest(request, response);
    }

    /** 
     * Returns a short description of the servlet.
     * @return a String containing servlet description
     */
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

Comment: I don't see servlets supported on godaddy.com. Am I missing something?

Comment: I tested one servlet package that comes with tomcat in webapps FOLDER as example, that was working fine.

Comment: And you are sure you have a test.class under WEB-INF/classes? without any package name?

Comment: updated folder structure,test.java and web.xml

Comment: Are you able to verify that your servlet starts at all (log files)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running packageless servlets doesn't work in all circumstances. Classes in the default package are by specification invisible/unimportable to classes in a real package. As far as I know, only certain Tomcat + JVM + Windows version combinations allows for that. But you should never rely on that environmental dependency. You should always put your servlets (preferably also all other Java classes!) in a package.

```
package com.example;

// ...

public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {

    // ...

}
```

The compiled class should end up in `/WEB-INF/classes/com/example/TestServlet.class` and the servlet mapping should be updated as follows:

```xml
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.example.TestServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>testServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/test</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also note that I fixed your classname to start with uppercase conform [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367).

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, I know that you're just beginning with servlets and that your servlet is just a dummy test example. I would only stress that emitting HTML inside a servlet that way is considered a bad practice. JSPs should be used for that. See also [our servlet wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info).

Comment: Tested the same code by keeping the test.java in com.sam package and modified web.xml..but FAILED.

Comment: Did you add the `package` declaration? Do you know how to compile classes in a package? Did you recompile the class from the package root on? I.e. you should be sitting in the folder containing `/com` folder and then compile `com/example/TestServlet.java`. Does Godaddy offer any log files where you can read startup errors?

Comment: Yeah, that I did. Basically I created whole new project, created com/example package and added test.java, added package name in test.java as well. Then modified web.xml

Comment: Would like to mention 2 things.1)Tested the same code by keeping the test.java in com.sam package and modified web.xml..but FAILED.2) My earlier test code was running on local machine successfully with same version of Tomcat as of goDaddy.

Answer (score 2):

GoDaddy does not support java on shared hosting space websites it seems:

http://support.godaddy.com/help/article/65/adding-a-java-servlet-to-your-web-site

Maybe with a dedicated server you can do that.